# Avoid frequent database connections

Tags: php, database, codeigniter, optimization

I was trying to read an excel file having 10000 rows. After reading each and every cell, my application should check whether the read value exist in database. This is working perfectly, but the issue is due to frequent database checking, the application seems to be very slow. Can any suggest a better alternative to this ? i'm using codeigniter framework with mysql.

Thanks and regards,

Tismon

Comment: Show us your code please! =)

Comment: Have you tried to see where the problem is? By inserting echo statements to show which bit of code is running, or using a profiler, you can work out what's the slow part. In your case, it could be the database queries, the reading from Excel, the database connection....

Comment: Without seeing any code I cannot be certain of my suggestion. However what I would do is query the DB once stick all the results in an array, and check the values against the array. But I may be misunderstanding your question.

Answer (score 1):

Reading 10000 rows shouldn't be such resource intensive, I think what really slows your application down is checking the whole database per each cell read. So you should avoid that.

The first thing came to my head is:
Add a Updated(date/time) field into each of your rows, and only check that whole row if the updated date/time is more recent than your last check.

Anyway showing more details will let us help you better.

Talk about what do your application need to check exactly or what does your excel file contains

Comment: The OP doesn't need to know if a row has to be updated. He needs to know if it exists, so a new column wouldn't make any sense.

Comment: Well the updated field or cell would be basically to know if that row wasn't checked, or if checked already it has changed, so the app would need to check it again, it's not to know if it has to be updated. Because I am not aware of the situatin 100% But I guess that his problem is that maybe he update the excel file, maybe 10 rows, but is checking the whole file(each cell) again and doing database queries

Comment: Sorry still doesn't make sense. If you can evaluate your new column, then you have already queried it. How should that reduce the queries?

Comment: You are evaluating it against a variable, not against the database, so that would not delay the application, maybe 0.0001s? against the database you would sum up the latency if it's remote, plus query time.

Even if he had to evaluate against the database, it would be 1 field, versus maybe 20 fields he has in that row, so just do some maths, that would be a lot of time saved.

Comment: Which variable? Anyway you have to evaluate it against the database (or where do you get the data from). You will still have to take all 20 (21) fields into account because you want to identify one specific row... I'm out, this leads us to nowhere.

Comment: a "last checked date/time" variable stored anywhere. And yes you will have to use up 5% more time checking 1 more field, but remember that you are saving 95% of time on every row that doesn't need to check, So if only 1 of every 20 rows doesn't need to be fully checked you are recovering the lost time, and in my opinion the fact is that at least 50% of the rows would not be updated, so you are saving a lot of time

Answer (score 0):

You can group the data which was read from the Excel file.

Let's say you have a column "zip code" in your Excel file. Then make a group of zip codes which may result in a list of 10 unique zip codes. Then you only have to make 10 queries to the database for each zip code and compare the returned list with the grouped data from the Excel file.